# How do I track a single user throughout my website using google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to track a single users path throughout my site all the way until conversion. Is there a way to legally do this through google analytics? I'm mainly trying to see if my homepage buttons are doing as well taking people through the whole process as my inner sites processes.

Comment: You could expose the Google Analytics client ID, which is unique to each user per session (so if the same user comes to your site on another browser or machine, then he/she would be counted as another user). The client ID could then be used in the Users Explorer report and you would be able to see all activity pertaining to that client ID.

Comment: @nyuen could you point me in a good direction or tutorial to start on how to do this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id?hl=en#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie is one resource, you could probably Google for others.

Answer (score 1):

Try **User Explorer** under **Audience**. You could use segments to then narrow down your search for specific users e.g. only those who accessed certain pages.